# Drive API:Insufficient permissions when changing owner

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have made a program in Java that generates a spreadsheet filled with statistics for VEX teams. My whole goal is to essentially have a program be able to generate a spreadsheet and change that sheet's ownership to a specific email. The Sheets functionality works completely, being able to create and modify spreadsheet values easily(using the Sheets API). The problem is when I try to change the ownership of the file using the Drive API, I get an "Insufficient Permission" message when running [Drive.permissions().create](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Permissions.Create.html).

When using the APIs explorer and testing it out myself, I was able to transfer ownership of spreadsheets, but I cannot do it within Java.

Here is how I create my GoogleCredential:

```
private void setCredential() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        //Create new transport
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        //Build authenticated credential
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setClientSecrets(Constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                                  Constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)
                .build();
        credential.setAccessToken(this.accessToken)
                  .setRefreshToken(Constants.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN);
        //Set class field
        this.credential = credential;
}
```

I noticed that I do not have any actual scopes here(which is weird, since this credential still works when the Sheets API does its work), in which I have looked around on how to input a proper scope here but found nothing. I don't know if this is why my program errors, or if it is for another reason.

This is how I call the method to transfer ownership:

```
private void transferOwnership(Drive driveService) throws IOException {
        //Print message
        System.out.printf("Transferring ownership to %s", this.usrEmail);
        //Build request body
        Permission body = new Permission()
                .setRole("owner")
                .setType("user")
                .setEmailAddress(this.usrEmail);
        //Execute Drive request
        Permission permission = driveService.permissions().create(this.spreadsheetId, body)
                .setFileId(this.spreadsheetId)
                .setEmailMessage("Test - Replace with something")
                .setSendNotificationEmail(true)
                .setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
                .setTransferOwnership(true)
                .setUseDomainAdminAccess(false)
                .setFields("emailAddress")
                .execute();
        //Print message
        System.out.printf("Ownership successfully transferred to %s", this.usrEmail);
}
```

These are my questions:

- Am I building my credential wrong? If so, how should I properly build it?
- Do I need to make two different credentials?(one for Sheets API, one for Drive API)
- How does my credential work fine with the Sheets API even though a scope isn't defined, but it does not work with the Drive API

EDIT: [The way I use the APIs explorer to change ownership](https://i.gyazo.com/fc2dce6a12e9605e8c49fc8596b53d88.png)

EDIT 2: This is how I get my access token. As for the refresh token, I use the Oauth Playground from google.

```
public void setAccessToken() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException{
        //Create a token response using refresh token and oauth credentials
        this.token_response = new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), 
                Constants.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN, Constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, Constants.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)
                .execute();
        //Set the access token
        this.accessToken = token_response.getAccessToken();   
    }
```

Comment: Need to know what scopes were authorized. You are setting a refresh token so where did that token come from and what scopes were used to create it.

Comment: @pinoyyid I've updated my post. I used to Oauth playground to get credentials for the Sheets API. I may see that I really would need to also get one for the Drive API. I'll try that and see how it works

Comment: I just checked it, and it seems like that I actually needed to create separate refresh tokens. One for the Sheets API, and one for the Drive API. I don't have much knowledge on the whole topic of authentication, as this whole program I am making is a learning experience.

Comment: while you can create separate Refresh Tokens, you can also bundle multiple scopes in a single RT. Also note that this is Authorisation, not Authentication.